# zsh bindkey commands overwritten after zshrc

Tags: macos, zsh, zshrc

I'm trying to remap my arrow keys, but something is overwriting or resetting my `bindkey` commands after the completion of `.zlogin`.

This is what I'm trying:

```
autoload -U up-line-or-beginning-search
autoload -U down-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N up-line-or-beginning-search
zle -N down-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey '^[[A' up-line-or-beginning-search
bindkey '^[[B' down-line-or-beginning-search
```

What I get from `bindkey` is:

```
"^[[A" up-line-or-history
"^[[B" down-line-or-history
```

What I've tried so far:

- Verified my intended `bindkey` with `cat -t` and double-checked with Ctrl-V + key press
- Moved key settings to the very end of `.zshrc`
- Created a one-line `.zlogin` file for a `bindkey` command
- Used the system logger to verify config files are running as expected
- Switched terminal apps

**What else can I try to find the source of these overwritten settings?**

zsh 5.8.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin21.0), macOS 12.5

Comment: Be careful: .zlogin is processed after .zshrc, but only for login shells. If you start a non-login shell, the settings in .zlogin don't take effect.

Comment: You can try starting zsh with `zsh -x`; that will print every command and you can check what it's doing. Use e.g. `zsh -x >& zshlog` to save it to a file.